# Invalid pointer with pthread_join

Tags: c

```
#include <pthread.h>            /* Thread related functions*/
#include <stdio.h>              /* Standard buffered input/output        */
#include <stdlib.h>             /* Standard library functions            */
#include <string.h>             /* String operations                     */

struct element{
FILE* file1;
FILE* file2;
int alone;
 };
int comp( const void* a, const void* b) //function for qsort
{


const int *a1 = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types 
const int *b1 = (const int *)b;
return *a1  - *b1; 
}

void* merge(void* filenames) //writes out files to two arrays, merges them and writes output to temp file and passes this tempfile through pthread_exit.
{
struct element* Data;
Data = (struct element*) filenames;
//char* fileA = Data->file1;
//char* fileB = Data->file2;
FILE* A = Data->file1;
FILE* B = Data->file2;

if(Data->alone!=1)
{
    //A = fopen(fileA, "r");
    int linesA = 0;
    int val=0;

        printf("FILE* A: %p \n", A);
        rewind(A);
    while(fscanf(A, "%d", &val) != EOF) 
        linesA++;
    printf("scanf\n");

    rewind(A);

    int* intarrA = (int*) malloc(linesA*sizeof(int));

    int i =0;

    for(;fscanf(A, "%d", &val) != EOF; i++)
        intarrA[i] = val;

    fclose(A);

    //FILE* B;
    //B = fopen(fileB, "r");
    int linesB = 0;

    while(fscanf(B, "%d", &val) != EOF) 
        linesB++;
    rewind(B);

    int* intarrB = (int*) malloc(linesB*sizeof(int));

    i =0;

    for(;fscanf(B, "%d", &val) != EOF; i++)
        intarrB[i] = val;

    fclose(B);

    int templength = linesA+linesB;
    int* inttemp = (int*) malloc(templength*sizeof(int));
    int help1 = 0;
    int help2 = 0;
    int temph = 0;
    for(i=0; i<templength; i++)
    {
        if(help1 == linesA)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for(j=help2; j<linesB; j++)
            {
                inttemp[temph] = intarrB[j];
                temph++;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(help2 == linesB)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for(j=help1; j<linesA; j++)
            {
                inttemp[temph] = intarrA[j];
                temph++;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(intarrA[help1]==intarrB[help2])
        {
            inttemp[temph]=intarrA[help1];
            help1++;
            help2++;
            temph++;
        }
        else if (intarrA[help1]<intarrB[help2])
        {
            inttemp[temph]=intarrA[help1];
            help1++;
            temph++;
        }
        else if(intarrA[help1]>intarrB[help2])
        {
            inttemp[temph]=intarrB[help2];
            help2++;
            temph++;
        }
    }
    FILE* filetowrite;
    filetowrite = tmpfile();
    for(i=0; i<temph; i++)
        fprintf(filetowrite ,"%d\n",inttemp[i]);
    printf("Merged %d lines and %d lines into %d lines\n",linesA,linesB,temph);
   // free(intarrA);
  //  free(intarrB);
  //  free(inttemp);
        printf("thread exit\n");
    pthread_exit((void*)filetowrite);
}
else{
    pthread_exit((void*)Data->file1);
        printf("ELSE MERGE \n");
}
}




void* worker(void* filen)
{
//left out to keep code short
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) //gets files through terminal, and sorts each one trhough worker function and then merges them with merge function and pthreads.
{
int zit =0;
void* tempf;
// tempf = malloc(sizeof(FILE));
argc = argc-1;
struct element* filenamelist; //I make an array of this to merge threads till there is only one element left
pthread_t *threadid;
threadid = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*argc);
int i;

for(i=1; i<=argc; i++) // part 1 passing the files to be qsorted
{
    pthread_create(&threadid[i-1], NULL, worker, (void*) argv[i]);
}
 //sorts each file fine. saves it as filename.sorted
for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
{
    pthread_join(threadid[i], NULL);
}
printf(" DONE WORKER\n");
int mall=0;
int size = 0;
if(size%2 ==0)
size = argc/2;
else
    size = argc/2 +1;
//int Osize = size;
int z=0;
int truth = 0;
// filenamelist = (struct element**) malloc(sizeof(struct element*)*argc);
// for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    filenamelist = (struct element*) malloc(argc*(sizeof(struct element)));
FILE** inputFiles = malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * (argc+argc));
for(i=1; i<=argc; i++)   //creates a list of elements with file ptrs
{
    filenamelist[(i-1)/2].alone = 0;

    if(i==argc  && i%2!=0)
    {

        char* tedious1 = (char*) malloc( (strlen(argv[i]) + 8 ));
        //char* tedious1 = (char*) malloc((strlen(argv[i+1]+7))*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tedious1,argv[i]);

        filenamelist[(i-1)/2].file1 = fopen(strcat(tedious1,".sorted"),"r");
        filenamelist[(i-1)/2].file2 = NULL;
        filenamelist[(i-1)/2].alone = 1;
        free(tedious1);
    }
    else
    {        

        char* tedious3 = (char*)malloc( (strlen(argv[i]) + 8 ));
        strcpy(tedious3,argv[i]);
//            printf("%s\n", tedious3);
        if(i%2 ==0)
        filenamelist[i/2].file2 = fopen(strcat(tedious3,".sorted"),"r");
        else
            filenamelist[i/2].file1 = fopen(strcat(tedious3,".sorted"), "r");
        free(tedious3);
    }    

}
/* for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("THIS IS: %d\n", i);
    if(filenamelist[i].alone ==1)
      {
          printf(" Alone \n");
        printf(" %p \n", filenamelist[i].file1);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("1 %p \n", filenamelist[i].file1);
        printf("2 %p \n", filenamelist[i].file2);
        }
}*/
//  pthread_t* threadid2;
//    threadid2 = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*(2*argc));
int xyz = 0;
int arab = 0;
int saudi = 0;
while(size>1) //Iterates through list till only one element left
{

    i = 0;
    pthread_t* threadid2;
    threadid2 = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*argc);
        printf("before create: %d, %p \n", i, tempf);
    for ( ; i<size;i++ )
    {
            pthread_create(&threadid2[i], NULL, merge, &filenamelist[i]); //<--- invalid pointer
        printf("AFTER create: %d, %p \n", i, threadid2[i]);
    }
    i = 0;
    for ( ; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("before join JOIN: %d, %p \n", i, tempf);
            pthread_join(threadid2[i], &tempf);
        printf("AFTER JOIN: %d, %p \n", i, tempf);
        if (i%2 == 0)
        {
            filenamelist[i/2].file1 = (FILE*)(tempf);
        }
        else
        {
            filenamelist[i/2].file2 = (FILE*)(tempf);
        }
        if(i%2==0 && i ==size-1)
            filenamelist[i].alone = 1;

        zit=0;
        truth = 0;
        while(zit<z)
        {
            if(inputFiles[zit] == (FILE*)(tempf))
                truth = 1;
            zit++;
        }
        if(truth != 1)
        {  
            inputFiles[z] = (FILE*)(tempf);
            z++;
        }
    }
    if(size==1)
    size = 0;
    else if (size % 2 == 0) 
    size = size/2;
    else
    size = (size/2)+1;
    free(threadid2);

}
pthread_t throwthread;
pthread_create(&throwthread, NULL, merge, &filenamelist[0]);
FILE* final;
pthread_join(throwthread, tempf);
int chd = 0;
final = (FILE*) tempf;
// if(0!=feof(tempf))
//   rewind(tempf);
//rewind(filenamelist[0]->file1);
int finish = 0;
//printf("file 1:%p",tempf);

while(fscanf(final, "%d", &chd) != EOF) 
    finish++;
rewind(final);

int* finarr = (int*) malloc(finish*sizeof(int));

int xx =0;

for(;fscanf(final, "%d", &chd) != EOF; xx++)
    finarr[xx] = chd;

//fclose(filetosort);

//qsort(intarr, i, sizeof(int),comp);

FILE* filetowrites;

filetowrites = fopen("sorted.txt", "w");

for(xx=0; xx<finish; xx++)
    fprintf(filetowrites, "%d\n", finarr[xx]);

fclose(filetowrites);

for(xx=0; xx<z; xx++)
    fclose(inputFiles[xx]);

free(inputFiles);
free(filenamelist);
free(finarr);
return 0;
}//end main func
```

This gives me an invalid pointer error. `threadid` is a `pthread_t*` pointing to an array.
I'm passing in a file pointer typecasted into a `void*` for the `pthread_exit((void*)fileptr);`
where `fileptr` is some `FILE*`.

And would it be okay to access `tempf` as `(FILE*) tempf`?

EDIT:I've tried everything that makes sense to me. Don't know why threadid2[i] or tempf would be an invalid pointer in the merge function. This is not something i can debug, Help please!

ERROR OCCURS ON FIRST JOIN

Comment: Well the invalid pointer error can't be from `tempf`; it must be from `threadid[i]`.  And yes it would be OK to cast `tempf` back to `FILE *` and use it, provided you close it later with `fclose()`.

Comment: What is an "invalid pointer error"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but if you are passing in filenames on the command line then it looks like you are allocating 1 more thread and filename than you actually have because argc will be 1 larger because it counts argv[0] which is the program name.

Comment: Does this happen on your first `join` or your last one (i.e, what's `i` when you crash)? How does `size` relate to `argc`? Create a complete example that you can post (it won't be many more lines that you have above) that repros the problem with threads that do nothing at all but exit (and maybe display a message).  You'll probably realize the problem as you're creating it...

Comment: Your comment on "invalid pointer" referrs to a line having `pthread_create()` but `pthread_join()`. **Where** does the actual error occurr? And is it a run-time or compile-time error?

Comment: I any case I'd strongly recommend to use error checking when doing system calls like `malloc()` et al and also the `pthread_*()` family of methods. This makes (debugging-)live much easier!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to check the return value of pthread_create.